# how to work with loop and break statement over numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, conditional-statements, break

I have this data array of **a** :

```
>>>a
array([[1., 2., 3.],
      [4., 5., 6.]], dtype=float32)
```

Now I want to do something like this with the data:

```
>>>for n in range (1,4):
>>>    a += 2
>>>    print(a)
[[3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 7. 8.]]
[[ 5.  6.  7.]
 [ 8.  9. 10.]]
[[ 7.  8.  9.]
 [10. 11. 12.]]
```

which will give me the final result of **a**:

```
>>> a
array([[ 7.,  8.,  9.],
       [10., 11., 12.]], dtype=float32)
```

if I want the iteration to stop for each element when the value is > 8,
which likely would give me the final result like this:

```
>>> a
array([[7., 8., 7.],
      [8., 7., 8.]], dtype=float32)
```

how to do that?

thank you!

Comment: Your loop occurs outside of the `a+= 2` calculation.  You can cap the values, but not stop the calculation.

Comment: the elements of `a` don't go through the loop individually.  All of `a` is evaluated at each `+=`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1., 2., 3.],
              [4., 5., 6.]], dtype=np.float32)

for n in range(1, 4):
    a += 2 * ((a + 2) <= 8)

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[[7. 8. 7.]
 [8. 7. 8.]]
```

The idea is to multiply 2 by a boolean mask that will be 1 if 2 can be added to the element of `a` else 0.

As an alternative, you could skip the for-loop altogether by doing the following:

```
a = 8 - (a % 2)
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[[7. 8. 7.]
 [8. 7. 8.]]
```

The above solution is based on the fact that the numbers in a that are even will end up as 8 and odd numbers as 7, this is of course assuming **that all the numbers in `a` are less than 8**.

Comment: thank you for the advice! but I actually want to get the idea on how to evaluate each element's value with the given condition inside the for loop, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: eh no it's my fault. I think I was just unclear about your answer, but I got it now. thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

**Code**

```
a = np.array([[1., 2., 3.],
      [4., 5., 6.]], dtype=np.float32)

for i in range(1, 4):
    a = np.where(a + 2 <= 8, a+2, a)
```

**Alternative** (requires Python 3.8+)

You can use the Walrus operator to avoid computing a + 2 twice:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    a = np.where((p:=a + 2) <= 8, p, a)
```

**Output**

```
print(a)
array([[7., 8., 7.],
       [8., 7., 8.]], dtype=float32)
```

**Explanation**

```
Syntax :numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
Parameters:
condition : When True, yield x, otherwise yield y.
```